# Update array of a document by using replaceOne or replace in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb

**Can we update array of a document by using replaceOne or replace in MongoDB?**

```
db.employeeDetails.find().pretty()
{
    "_id"  : ObjectId("587c99a3cc61ca283575bf75"),
    "eid"  : 1882031,
    "addr" : [
                {
                        "fNo"   :  8,
                        "bName" : "Abc Apts"    
                        "town"  : "My Town"
                }


             ]
}
```

Now I want to update the town, using replace or replaceOne. I don't want to read the document and then update.

Comment: Are you using a Spring DAO implementation for interacting with Mongo through Java?

Comment: Not SpringDAO I'm doing with Mongo driver

Comment: what is the input ? How do you know what town to update in which document ?

Comment: I want to update employeeDetails ,  you can see there is an array for address where I'm storing Flat No.,Build Name and Town, in my collection there could me more than 1000 employee with different eid. Right now I am reading count then checking is count is greater than 0 then updating else doing insertion. But now I want to avoid reading I want to match the pattern if it matches then directly update else insert.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **update** **operations** like this.

```
 db.test.update(
{ _id: ObjectId("57f4997e551422c9cc5eeff2") },
   { $set: 
      {"test.0": { "scores" :89, "name" : "halim" }
      }
   }
)
```